# Django - Knowing which templates calls the base

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I want to know which (or view) calls the **base.html** for showing one or another div. Or, if it's possible, I want to pass a parameter from **home.html** to **base.html** when I use `{% extends '/parts/base.html' %}` to know what div prints.

I.E: I have a sidebar in my template, and I want to show a button to collapse/un-collapse it, and that button is in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my problem adding a {%block extrabutton %} {% endblock %} and adding the code in the view that calls base.html.